# Bootstrap how to avoid column break with min width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have following code, I need two columns and i have min width for these two columns to support mobile browsers.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: blue;min-width: 250px;">A</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: red;min-width: 250px;">B</div>
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: green;min-width: 500px">
            C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the screen size is less than 500px, first div and second div go to two lines. But instead of that I want to keep them in the same Row

How it looks in small screen

[image: in small screen, less than 600px]

How it should be in small screen. (This is how it looks in large screen size)

[image: in large screens, and this is how it should look in small screen]

---

How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Edit**

In my real code, I used bootstrap order. So In large screen order is A C B, but in small screens A B C. So I can't remove row class.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` This tag should add to support mobile.

Comment: because you are not making a row.

Comment: Actually i didnt add that code, there is a row outside.

Comment: I have updated my answer below to suit your requirement. However, I am still not able to understand about the order you need? in large screens you want A(50%) to be followed by C(100%) and then in thrid row Column B(50%)?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In large screen, A 50%, C 50% and B is 100%. I could handle it with order-x in bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your code and it works fine for me. Did you check any other outside tags which might be causing this ?

[image]

Comment: There is a something missing in the questions.   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">. This needs to be add to support mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **Parent DIV**:- See below example.

```
<div class="parent_div">
   <div class="col-6" style="min-width: 250px">1</div>
   <div class="col-6" style="min-width: 250px">2</div>
   <div class="col-12" style="min-width: 600px">3</div>
</div>
```

And Use CSS

```
.parent_div{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
.col-6{
   width: 50%;
}
.col-12{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes good! my thought better to create two rows.. responsive.. and plz correct `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: In my situation I can't add parent_div, there should be bootstrap row class. Because I have used col-md etc... and bootstrap column ordering too

Comment: Then add **.parent_div** CSS on class **.row**

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the HTML markup for the same. Following will solve your issue hopefully.

```css
.col-a {
  background-color: purple;
}

.col-b {
  background-color: red;
}

.col-c {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-a">Column A</div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-b">Column B</div>
    <div class="col col-c">Column C </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
.div{
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
   <div class="col-6" style="min-width: 250px">1</div>
   <div class="col-6" style="min-width: 250px">2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-12" style="min-width: 600px">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

look carefully,

I assume you want to use pure `bootstrap` 
then you should have to use bootstrap breakpoints.
here in code below, I used `768px` as a breakpoint and not `600px`
so if it is must use `600px` then you can hard code it else you can use BS breakpoints.

And I hope the code below will help you, again don't compromise with your requirements, if `768px` doesn't suit you, you can use 540px or use media-query and hard code it for `600px`.

```html
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-6">1 one</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-6">2 two</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">3 three</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "flex" but you need to remove inline min-width, if you can not remove so you need add !important tag for min-width Please see below.
Apply css @media max-width(500px)

```css
.container .row {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
} 
.container .row .col-6{
   width: 50%;
   min-width:0 !important;
}
.container .row .col-12{
    width: 100%;
    min-width:0 !important;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: blue;min-width: 250px;">A</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: red;min-width: 250px;">B</div>
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: green;min-width: 500px">
            C
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue. All I had to do was set 500px min-width to the row class.